# "Positional arguments must occur before named arguments & Too many positional arguments:" error

Tags: flutter

Can someone please tell me how to correct these two errors? I tried several different approaches but wasn't successful.

Both issues are regarding the "class SecondScreen".

I don't understand where should I make the changes. This might be a very simple question. But I'd be glad if one of you could give me some insight on this issue.

I went through some sample codes & tutorials but couldn't find an effective one.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'firstapp',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data = ["one", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0,horizontal: 10.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0,horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Text(data[i], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18.0)),
                    onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context, 
                      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(i)), 
                    );
                     },
                    )
                  ),
                  Divider(color: Colors.black),
                ],
                ),
              )
          ],),
      )
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    List data = ["one", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
    List data1 = ["this", "that", "here", "hello", "ahoy"];
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          //title: new Text("Second Screen"),

          Container(
          child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

          Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 6.0),
          child: Text(data[i], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25.0)), 
           ),
          ]
          ),
          ),


          Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 2.0),
          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Text(data1[i],style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 12.0)
          ),
          ]
          ),
          ),

        )
        ),
        );

  }
}
```

1. Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
   Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named `arguments.dart(extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named)`
2. Positional arguments must occur before named arguments.
   Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named `arguments.dart(positional_after_named_argument)`

Comment: Please post errorlog also

Comment: If you wanna pass something in your SecondScreen() constructor , you must have to defined constructor   inside your SecondScreen class. And after you will felt like superhero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with as,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'firstapp',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.teal
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data = ["one", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            child: FlatButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Text(data[i], style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
                                );
                              },
                            )
                        ),
                        Divider(color: Colors.black),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],),
        )
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List data = ["one", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
  List data1 = ["this", "that", "here", "hello", "ahoy"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Second Screen"),),
        body: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 6.0),
                    child: Text(data[i], style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0)),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

In your listview.builder where you are using routing to navigate to page **"SecondScreen(i)"** you are passing "i" as parameter in constructor. But, inside the **SecondScreen** class you are not creating any constructor with such parameter is issue.

Another issue in your build method, you are using 2 Padding widgets to your body directly as a single child. you can use column widget to linearly add childs one by one.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update (Dart `2.17`)

You can now place named arguments before positional arguments. For example:

```dart
void main() {
  foo('John', married: false); // Always worked
  foo(married: true, 'Tony'); // Works now (with Dart 2.17)
}

void foo(String name, {bool? married}) {
  print('Is $name married? $married');
}
```