# how do i put word on top of new container on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello i have some problem with my flutter design
i want to make a box with rounded border using container
and on the top of this box i want to make a text and text looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWEbX.jpg)
but when i wrote the code the text is cannot be up look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhSPs.jpg)

this is my code

```
                height: 440.0,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                      )),
                  child: new Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                      child: Text('Email'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Align` for keeping always on head.

```
Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                )),
            child: new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                child: Text('Email'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

output:

[image]

Comment: where do i put stack?

Comment: updated my answer please have a look not need to use stack

Comment: okay thanks btw  is there any way to add textfieldform on the new container?

Comment: yap, you can try with the column

Comment: its says too many positional arguments, and positional argument mus occur before named arguments when i add column or child

Comment: please make a separate question I will share an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue,
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: how do i put form textfield?

Comment: You can add a column widget and put all the other widgets inside the column widget.

Comment: but its says too many positional arguments, and positional argument mus occur before named arguments when i add column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055590/positional-arguments-must-occur-before-named-arguments-too-many-positional-ar?rq=1 Can this link help your answer?